# Is using operator+ in operator+= slower than not using it?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, operator-overloading

Say I have a vector class like so:

```
struct Vector
{
    int x, y;

    Vector operator+(Vector rhs)
    {
        return Vector(x + rhs.x, y + rhs.y);
    }
}
```

And I want to add `operator+=`. I have two options:

This:

```
Vector& operator+=(Vector rhs)
{
    *this = *this + rhs;
    return *this;
}
```

Or this:

```
Vector& operator+=(Vector rhs)
{
    x += rhs.x;
    y += rhs.y;
    return *this;
}
```

Applying this to all other `operator_=`s using their respective math operators and assignment operators, and `operator!=` using `operator==`, would there be any realistic performance degradation due to the additional operator calls, assuming these operators are used extremely often?

Comment: At least you are returning a new Vector from the + operator, which is slower than just returning a reference to an already existing struct.

Comment: In your specific case, any compiler can optimize operations on two `int`s to remove any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Generally speaking I would say it's better to write `operator+` (the less efficient operation) in terms of `operator+=` (the more efficient operation).

```
Vector& Vector::operator+=(Vector rhs)
{
    x += rhs.x;
    y += rhs.y;
    return *this;
}

Vector operator+(Vector lhs, Vector rhs)
{
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```

Although your Vector class is small enough that it's probably not going to make a huge difference,

Comment: Note that your `operator+` inhibits RVO.

Comment: And also copies both operands.